# Mixer vs JamHub?

Tags: practice, setup, mixer

I had made another thread with a question about connecting instruments and headphones [here](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/42353/connecting-multiple-instruments-into-2-headphones) ,but before I make my final decision I have a few last questions.

1. If I get the mixer, which is [this](http://www.sweetwater.com/store/detail/502),can I connect a [headphone amp](http://www.sweetwater.com/store/detail/HA400),electric guitar, effect board for the guitar and an electronic drum to this mixer and have the same sound quality as the JamHub?
2. Is it possible to have all these things plugged into this mixer?
3. Is it possible to plug a phone or sound system in addition to all these equipments to the mixer?
4. For a long period of time it's probably just going to be me and my friend jamming,so is it worth buying a JamHub or is the mixer a cheaper,better way to play music quietly?

I would greatly appreciate any help.
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can plug your guitar into your effects unit and plug that unit (pedal or board) into the Left **"line in"** 1/4 inch input - in either channel two or channel three.  The left input is for a mono signal.

You can plug the stereo output from the electronic drum module into the left and right input of whichever stereo input channel you did not use for the guitar effects unit.  This would leave channel one open for another line input or a microphone.

You can connect the headphone amplifier to the headphone output labeled "phone" on the mixer using a 1/4 inch TRS to 1/4 inch TRS stereo patch cable.

You can input a signal from your phone or other source into the left/right RCA jack input on the mixer.  You can also output a signal from the RCA out jacks.  If inputting from your phone or other mp3 device that has a 1/8 inch headphone jack, you will need a 1/8" TRS to dual RCA cable.

If you start playing for an audience in the future - you can send the entire mix into external powered PA speakers or into an external power amp (to drive passive PA speakers) from the L and R main out jacks on the mixer.

As far as your question about if that would sound as good as a jam hub through your headphones - I have no way to know the answer to that question without trying them both side by side.  You can look at expense and future potential use of each system as a deciding factor if you are not able to do your own test.

If I had to guess, I would say that either the JamHub or the mixer with headphone amp would allow you and your jam mates to hear everything you need to hear and control the volume in each headphone and practice together without external amplification.  So I believe either system will accomplish your goal.

Whichever system you choose - have fun jammin!

[image]  [image]

Comment: Rockin Cowboy,you are amazing.Always helping me out!Thank you so much for your detailed explanation! I'm not very good with wires and often get confused,so you are helping me a ton! I really appreciated it!

Comment: @RockinCowboy It's great that you helped the OP, but as a stack rule, we don't answer questions on equipment recommendations because they're primarily opinion-based and because they're unlikely to help future people.

Comment: @jjmusicnotes - it would seem that there is no 'brand' recommendation, only comparisons with different ways in which to achieve an end. Maybe 'jamhub' has become eponymous.The question (and answer, therefore)  comes just within our remit, I believe.

Comment: @jjmusicnotes OP did not ask for brand recommendation.  He did mentioned models he was considering as an example.  The way I see it - OP had a goal to provide a means of silent collaborative practice and wished to further explore the merits of alternate ways to accomplish said goal as evidenced by the question title.  He was not asking which brand mixer or which brand headphone amp to use.  But I always welcome your input and wisdom as a long standing member of Stack and very knowledgeable practitioner of your craft.

Comment: @RockinCowboy This is precisely what I wanted to know.I am not interested in brands,I am only interested in how to accomplish my goal as cheap as possible,which is practicing with headphones.I believe the information you have provided will help other people who desire to practice quietly and who do not understand how these devices work together.Thanks again.

Comment: @Tim Alright, I guess I can understand that. I suppose I would prefer some of the language to be changed such that it doesn't come across like the OP is getting personal advice - perhaps just some rewording to sound a bit more general?

Comment: @RockinCowboy You are kind; just wanted to point something out in case you had forgotten or simply didn't know. My reaction is less, I think, from your answer, and more from the wording of the original question.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to Rockin's answer, the only disadvantage will be that there will only be one sound mix in all of the headphones with the cheaper alternative. So if one of the listeners wants more of himself, then everyone gets more of him!

Comment: Actually I believe the headphone amp OP is considering (pictured in my answer) has individual separate volume controls for each headphone.  This should allow the individual musicians to adjust their volume independently.

Comment: @RockinCowboy - true - but that's each person's in ear volume. I'm considering the MIX which will be the same for everybody, I think.

Comment: Oh yes - absolutely.  You are correct.  As I re-read your answer - I understand what you meant.  You meant the overall mix would be the same in each headphone.  So to add to your answer - If the guitarist wants his guitar louder than the drums but the drummer wants the drums louder than the guitar, the mixer/headphone amp solution will not allow for both whereas the jamhub solution would allow for each musician to tailor the overall mix to his/her liking.

Comment: @Tim Would a mixer such as [this](http://www.sweetwater.com/store/detail/802) solve this issue?I'm not sure if it would work but it seems to have a level knob for each entry.

Comment: @user2752798 - I doubt it. I've used several of these over the years, and they seem to have only stereo output. However, if one input was panned right, the other left, there would probably be some sort of remix facility, but quite rudimentary. The level pot for each input would only give the same balance for all outputs.