# need help to figure out equipment needed for a silent rehearsal room

Tags: practice, setup, mixer, jamming

Hey folks i am trying to figure out things i will need to buy for a silent rehearsal room for my band so we can hear it in headphones.
we dont have budget for sound proofing and 
i dont want to buy a jamhub cause it cost twice as much in my country so far i am thinking of buying a electric drum kit which will go in a alto zmx 164 fx usb-16 channel mixer along with other instruments and vocals, then the signal will go into a behringer ha400 ultra headphone amplifier and through it into our headphones so do you think this will work or can you help me with a better option.and will i be able to make saparate hadphone mix using aux send from the mixer. Any help or suggestion is appreciated. THANKS ^_^

Comment: If a jamhub is cheaper in another country, the postage won't add up to the same price as the item. Buy it elsewhere and have it shipped.

Comment: You may find the answers to this similar question helpful (http://music.stackexchange.com/q/42913/16897)

Comment: Also you might find this helpful (http://music.stackexchange.com/a/42364/16897)

Answer (score 2):

The setup you describe is pretty much the standard way to do "silent" rehearsing. It may not give you as much flexibility and easy control (specifically for rehearsing) as devices like the jamhub, but I find the jamhub outrageously expensive, regardless of where you buy it. You can buy a supperb 12 channel mixer (much better investment for a band) and a headphone distributer by much less than what the jamhub would cost.

I had a look at the zmx specs, and it has both 4 AUX sends per channel and 4 submix buses, so you have a couple of different ways of creating specific mixes for each musician in the band.

However with the behringer ha400 you only have 1 input, albeit a stereo one, so you will not be able to able to distribute individual mixes with that one. If you really want to do that you need a multi-input headphone amplifier, like the inexpensive [Millenium HP4](https://www.thomann.de/gb/millenium_hp_4.htm?ref=search_rslt_hp4_234787_0) or the more sophisticated but more expensive [Behringer HA4700](https://www.thomann.de/gb/behringer_ha4700_powerplay_proxl_kopfhoererverstaerker.htm).

Answer (score -1):

Try the Scarlett 18i20. Its mix control can fulfill your separate headphone mix need, using either its 10 mono output or 5 stereo output, without adding more gear.